# How to create auto scrolling UITextView in the Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone

I try to create a UITexView with auto scrolling when press button start. And have a button stop, when pressed it will stop scrolling. Pressing button start again and it will continues to scroll down. How to handle this function.
I have research some code that this code below work with me.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSLog(@"%f %f",_txvSentence.contentSize.width , _txvSentence.contentSize.height);
    if (scrollingTimer == nil) {
        scrollingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(35.0/1000.0)
                                                          target:self
                                                        selector:@selector(autoscrollTimerFired:)
                                                        userInfo:nil
                                                         repeats:YES];

        NSLog(@"%@",scrollingTimer);
    }
}
- (void)autoscrollTimerFired:(NSTimer*)timer {
    CGPoint scrollPoint = self.txvSentence.contentOffset;
    //scrollPoint = CGPointMake(scrollPoint.x, scrollPoint.y + 1);

    scrollPoint = _txvSentence.contentOffset;
    scrollPoint.y= scrollPoint.y+1;
    [_txvSentence setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:NO];

    //[self.txvSentence setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:NO];
}
```

But i cannot stop this animation. And how to set dynamic duration such as when come to the end of text it automatically stop.

Sorry because my bad english. If not understand please tell me where I will explain it clearly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone Auto-scroll UITextView but allow manual scrolling also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088960/iphone-auto-scroll-uitextview-but-allow-manual-scrolling-also)

Comment: Try to use [DAAutoScroll](https://github.com/danielamitay/DAAutoScroll). It is easy to implement

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

CGFloat scrollHeight = 100;


//===

- (void) spinWithOptions: (UIViewAnimationOptions) options {
    // this spin completes 360 degrees every 2 seconds
    [UIView animateWithDuration:10
                          delay:0
                        options:options
                     animations:^{
                         self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, scrollHeight);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         if (finished) {
                             if (animating) {
                                 // if flag still set, keep spinning with constant speed
                                 [self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction];
                             } else if (options != UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut) {
                                 // one last spin, with deceleration
                                 [self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut];
                             }
                         }

                     }];
}


- (void) startAnimating {
    if (!animating) {
        animating = YES;
        [self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear |      UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction];
    }
}

- (void) stopAnimating {
    // set the flag to stop spinning after one last 90 degree increment
    animating = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSTimer.

```
// Global var
CGFloat scrollHeight = MAX_HEIGHT;
CGFloat currentOffsetY = 0.0f;
NSTimer *timer;

self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:YOUR_TIME_INTERVAL target:self selector:@selector(scrollText:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void)scrollText:(NSTimer *)timer {
    currentOffsetY++;
    if (currentOffsetY >= MAX_HEIGHT) {
        [self.timer invalide];
    }
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, currentOffsetY);
}

// Your button action
- (void)stopAnimation:(UIButton *)button {
    [self.timer invalide];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. The variable YOUR_TIME_INTERVAL I confuse to put in this because if I don't press stop button it will scroll to the end of text and stop.

Comment: @nvtien YOUR_TIME_INTERVAL is the frequency of the timer to call scrollText: method. E.g. If you set it as 1.0f/10.0f, the scroll view will scroll up one pixel every 1.0/10.0 second. The above code should automatically stop the timer when currentOffsetY >= MAX_HEIGHT